# create new checkboxes each time a button is clicked and remove earlier added ones tikinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to generate checkboxes based on button click. But when it is clicked checkboxes keep adding. Instead, I need to removed earlier created checkboxes and create again 2 checkboxes. Instead of keep growing the checkboxes how can remove the earlier created ones? Following is my coded.

```
# Import Tkinter library
from tkinter import *

# Create an instance of tkinter frame
win = Tk()

# Set the geometry of Tkinter frame
win.geometry("700x250")

# Define Function to print the input value
def display_input():
    print("Input for Python:", var1.get())
    print("Input for C++:", var2.get())


# Define empty variables
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()

display_button_check = Button(win,
                             text = 'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO',
                             font = ('Arial', 11),
                             height = 1,
                             width =20,
                             bg = '#B0E0E6',
                             fg = 'Black',
                             command = lambda: get_checkbox_status()
                            ).pack()
def get_checkbox_status():
    # Define a Checkbox
    t1 = Checkbutton(win, text="Python", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
    t1.pack()
    t2 = Checkbutton(win, text="C++", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
    t2.pack()



win.mainloop()
```

Comment: why not just update the text of the checkbutton? Is there a reason you want to recreate the checkbutton?

Comment: Hi Art... In the actual function, the number of checkboxes that I'm creating are dynamic. when a file is loaded based on the button, its null columns are listed as check boxes. For one dataframe, it is 1, for another it is 5. Issue is eack time I'm loading the file, the checkboxes keep adding. I do not have a place to destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You will have to make the checkboxes global variables in this case. You can also add them to a list.

```py
...
t1 = Checkbutton(win, text="Python", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
t2 = Checkbutton(win, text="C++", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)

def get_checkbox_status():
    t1.pack()
    t2.pack()
...
```

In case you are trying to remove the already packed checkboxes, you can use `destroy()` method. Do note that this will completely delete the widget.

```py
...
t1 = Checkbutton(win, text="Python", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
t2 = Checkbutton(win, text="C++", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
t1.pack()
t2.pack()

def get_checkbox_status():
    t1.destroy()
    t2.destroy()
...
```

If you just want to hide the checkboxes, you can use `pack_forget()` in this case.

```py
...
def get_checkbox_status():
    t1.pack_forget()
    t2.pack_forget()
...
```

In case you are trying to create a togglable setup, you can do it as follows:

```
...
t1 = Checkbutton(win, text="Python", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
t2 = Checkbutton(win, text="C++", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=display_input)
t1.pack()
t2.pack()
active = True

def get_checkbox_status():
    global active
    if active:
        t1.pack_forget()
        t2.pack_forget()
    else:
        t1.pack()
        t2.pack()
    active = not active
...
```